# Where does maven install jars?

Tags: java, maven

So I copied a Repo from my team lead's work-space into my work-space. Literally using unix CP.

Now whenever I run `mvn clean install`, it installs the compiled jar into the his work space.

I have checked the pom.xml in the repo and it doesn't explicitly define the target location.

I've also checked my `printenv`. There is no mention of my TL's work-space in any of the environment variables. Where is the location of my TL's work-space coming form?

Comment: you should check the settings file from your maven setup.

Comment: Where would it be?

Comment: do you know where your maven is installed? check there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the .m2 repository there is a settings.xml which normally includes a path, since you just copied it you will most certenly have his path there

- Windows: C:\Users\USERNAME.m2\settings.xml
- Linux:/home/USERNNAME/.m2/settings.xml

In the file there is a 'localRepository' tag (Check it)

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>SomePath/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <offline>false</offline>
  ...
</settings>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find your installed JARs and dependencies in your local repository.

By default, you can find it here:

- Windows: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.m2\repository`
- Linux: `/home/USERNNAME/.m2/repository`
- MacOS: `/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository`